# Xcode - resource already exists?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm simply trying to add a file to my Xcode resources folder and it fails claiming the file already exists, which simply isn't true.

I assume it has a record of the name and is confusing itself, I tried performing a 'clean' but this didn't help. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click on project and get info.Then search for the file.And then delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Try fully closing/re-opening Xcode and failing that, reboot yet?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, use the file filter at the bottom of the project navigator to triple check the file is not there.

If the file is definatly not in the project sometimes Xcode gets confused when you delete a file and the file may actually be on disk. So check the actual project directory on disk to ensure that your file is not in there.

Quick way to get to your project directory, right click the project file (or any file) and select `Show in Finder` or at the very top of the Xcode window `cmd` + `click` the project title and select the folder it is in.